# Matplotlib pyplot in real time

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a while function that generates two lists of numbers and at the end I plot them using matplotlib.pyplot.

I'm doing

```
while True:
    #....
    plt.plot(list1)
    plt.plot(list2)
    plt.show()
```

But in order to see the progression I have to close the plot window.
Is there a way to refresh it with the new data every x seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most robust way to do what you want is to use `matplotlib.animation`. Here's an example of animating two lines, one representing sine and one representing cosine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sin_l, = ax.plot(np.sin(0))
cos_l, = ax.plot(np.cos(0))
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
dx = 0.1

def update(i):
    # i is a counter for each frame.
    # We'll increment x by dx each frame.
    x = np.arange(0, i) * dx
    sin_l.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
    cos_l.set_data(x, np.cos(x))
    return sin_l, cos_l

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=51, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

For your particular example, you would get rid of the `while True` and put the logic inside that `while` loop in the `update` function. Then, you just have to make sure to do `set_data` instead of making a whole new `plt.plot` call.

More details can be found in [this nice blog post](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), [the `animation` API](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html), or [the `animation` examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/animation/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the "animation" feature.

Here is [an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/animation_demo.html)

[This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html?highlight=animation) is a second one.